# How to shutdown the computer when a specific application is closed in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

I am using Windows 10 64 bit. I have an application running and when it is done doing what it does, it closes.

Is there a way to shutdown my computer automatically when that program closes?

I did find a program called Shutdown scheduler SDS or something like that but it doesn't support the newer Windows operating systems.

Comment: But this is superuser.com                                                                                 I did not write it. I did already find a solution however. I am now using a visual basic script to check if process is running and shutdown the computer if it is not.

Comment: Batch file: `start /wait <Program>` + `shutdown -f -s -t 00`?

Comment: @user3757605: oops, my apologies!  So used to writing that (or similar) comment on StackOverflow since I spend a lot more time there.